# Creating shift-reduce / reduce-reduce free grammars

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, shift-reduce-conflict, reduce-reduce-conflict

I'm trying to implement a simple Java like language parser in sablecc, although I'm constantly running into `shift-reduce` / `reduce-reduce` problems when implementing `if`, `while` and `block` statements.

For instance, I've considered the following:

`stmts` = `stmt*`;

`stmt` = `if_stmt` | `block_stmt` | `while_stmt`;

`block_stmt` = `{ stmts }` | `;` ;

`while_stmt` = `while` `(` `predicate` `)` `{` `stmts` `}` | `while` `(` `predicate` `)` `;`

This grammar, will, for instance, cause the problem that when you have something of the form

```
while (true) ;
```

the parser won't be able to know whether to reduce just `;` (from `block_stmt`) or the full `while (true);` (from `while_stmt`).

I've been reading everywhere the reasons for the `shift-reduce` / `reduce-reduce` problems and I think I understand them. But one thing is to know what causes them, and another completely different is knowing how to structure grammars such that I avoid them. I've tried implementing grammars in very different ways and I end up with problems nonetheless.

I guess that instead of just trying to run from a specific `ss` / `rr` problem, there must a kind of paradigm to follow such to avoid this kinds of issues? I believe my way of approaching the problem must be totally wrong :(

Any resources around on how to build from scratch a grammar without falling into all these pitfalls? The resources on this matter tend to be either really easy (stating the obvious `if then else` problem) or fully flagged grammars, which are kind of impenetrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your grammar is specified so that eg the semicolon can be interpreted either as the semicolon of while_stmt or that of block_stmt... no sorry not that but somehow the grammar is redundant because { stmt } appears twice on RHS. Normally you would do

```
 stmts ::= stmt | stmts stmt
 block_stmt ::= { stmts }
 stmt ::= ... | block_stmt | ;     // empty
 while_stmt ::= while ... stmt
```